# Animate a view appearing/disappearing below Android Toolbar

Tags: android, android-animation

My current Android application requires a view to slide down/up from below the Toolbar.

I would like the animation to be "Buttery" smooth and incorporate fade and slide aspects.

The code I have is not satisfactory for a number of reasons.

it only works once, then my view still "appears" however its invisible!

it is far from "Buttery" smooth

heres my code

```
 private fun animateContainer(height: Int, visibility: Int) {
        myContainer.animate()
            .translationY(height.toFloat())
            .setDuration(300)
            .setListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation)
                    animation?.removeAllListeners()
                    myContainer.clearAnimation()
                    myContainer.visibility = visibility
                }
            })
    }
```

Initially my view is hidden, when the user clicks a button the view should slide down and fade in, pushing down the visible view which is always shown.

the call that makes the container appear is

```
animateSearchContainer(myContainer.height, View.VISIBLE)
```

the call that makes the container disappear is

```
animateSearchContainer(-pdfSearchContainer.height, View.GONE)
```

I do not understand why, after the first cycle of making the view appear and disappear the view is not visible when static, however as it transitions off the screen it momentarily appears.

I also do not understand why the animation is so "jerky"

Is it possible to achieve my desired effect of smoothly making my view slide down and up consistently?

where have I gone wrong?

I did also have `.alpha(targetAlpha)` as part of the animation but removed it as I thought that was causing my issue.

Comment: you are calling animateSearchContainer() to appear and disappear, but the method with your given code is called animateContainer() , is that on porpuse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it might be the use of View.GONE which makes the View not only invisible, but also not taking any more space in the layout. You might be better off using View.INVISIBLE.

Second thing is these calls :

```
animation?.removeAllListeners()
myContainer.clearAnimation()
```

will reset the animation as soon as it ends, no wonder it only works once, you should probably remove these, they make no sense if you want continuos up and down animations.

Third thing is you are changing the Visibility in onAnimationEnd(), which as the name states, gets executed as soon as the animation ends. So you are animating an Invisible View and then changing it to Visible, no wonder the animation cant be seen.

Fourth thing is why do you want to change the Visibility anyway? If it slides behind the Toolbar correctly it is also not visible, so you can actually cut the Visibility part and probably the whole onAnimationEnd() method completely.

For smoothness you use an [Interpolator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator).
Most common one is [AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator) :

```
myContainer.animate()
        .translationY(height.toFloat())
        .setDuration(300)
        .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
```

So it all comes up to this :

```
 private fun animateContainer(height: Int) {
        myContainer.animate()
            .translationY(height.toFloat())
            .setDuration(300)
            .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
 }
```

This should work as long as you have the correct height value as parameters :

```
animateContainer(myContainer.height)  // appear
animateContainer(-pdfSearchContainer.height)  // disappear
```

If you want to 'push down' a view you will have to animate this as well or you put them both in a container f.e. an ConstraintLayout and animate the whole container